# Avoiding relative paths in Angular CLI

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I'm using the latest Angular CLI, and I've created a custom components folder which is a collection of all components.

For example, `TextInputComponent` has a `TextInputConfiguration` class which is placed inside `src/components/configurations.ts`, and in `src/app/home/addnewuser/add.user.component.ts` where I use it there is:

```
import {TextInputConfiguration} from "../../../components/configurations";
```

This is fine but as my app gets larger and deeper the `../` increases, how do I handle this?

Previously, for SystemJS, I would configure the path through `system.config.js` as below:

```
System.config({
..
 map : {'ng_custom_widgets':'components' },
 packages : {'ng_custom_widgets':{main:'configurations.ts', defaultExtension: 'ts'},
)};
```

How do I produce the same for webpack using Angular CLI?

Comment: FYI ive tried adding paths to tsconfig.json doesnt work `  "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"]
    }, ` and in the app.component ` import {TextInputConfiguration} from "@components/configurations";`

Comment: I think that's because your path for `@components` is wrong. See my answer; we have a `lib/` directory in a similar place and it works fine.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Per [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1465#issuecomment-236054952), you can add your application source via `paths` in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,  
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      ...,
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can import absolutely from `app/` or `components/` instead of relative to the current file:

```
import {TextInputConfiguration} from "@components/configurations";
```

Note: **`baseUrl` must be specified if `paths` is.**

See also

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

Comment: Awesome! , configured it according to your new answer, sailed through!!

Comment: for anyone else in future, I had to set the option of `baseUrl` along with the answer to get it work.

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi set it to what?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: to root directory of my app. even after that, VS Code was able to resolve the dependency but `Webpack's ts loader` was still giving error of `unable to resolve module`. To fix that, I had to add `alias` and `modules` properties in my `webpack.config`

Comment: yes, I tried with `"."` but I had to explicitly add `baseUrl` and `paths` in webpack config to get it work.

Comment: I spent hours with this and finally gave up. Webpack is buggy. Even if I added the same paths to its resolve, it wouldn't run normally.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seme to work anymore? Using this verbatim, and it still can't seem to figure out the paths.

Comment: It says `error TS2307: Cannot find module '@service/example/example.service'`. I've got `"baseUrl": "./src/app/"` and `"paths": {"@serivce/*": ["service/*"]}`

Comment: What if the project is a library ? How to export these paths mappings to the client application ?

Comment: It's kind of pointless to specify the same path component in the key and in the value. The above example can be simplified/reduced as: `"@/*": ["src/app/*"]` and then you can import from `@/components` or `@/any_other_folder` with just that one path mapping. Also, I think you have an error in your config: your paths are relative to `.`, but angular `app` folder is in `./src/app` not in `./app`.

Comment: This works but VS Code doesn't pick up on it and gives a warning/error.

Comment: remember to 'restart ts server' in command palette in vscode

Comment: baseUrl should be "./", while the paths aliases should also contain "src". e.g.  `"@app/*": ["src/app/*"]`

Answer (score 26):

Thanks to **[jonrsharpe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41460972/3621001)** for pointing me in right direction. Although, after adding the `paths`, as defined in answer, I was still not able to make it work. For anyone else facing same problem as me in future, here's what I did to fix the issues.

I have a *shared module* and its services are being used in multiple components, so...

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "baseUrl": ".", //had to add this too
        "paths": {
            "@shared/*": ["src/app/modules/shared/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

After this, *VS Code* was able to resolve the `import` but I still got following error from `webpack` while compilation.

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

To fix this I had to add

1. **`baseUrl of tsconfig`** in **`webpack's resolve.modules`**
2. **`paths of tsconfig`** in **`webpack's resolve.alias`**

**webpack.config.js:**

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['*', '.js', '.ts'],
  modules: [
    rootDir,
    path.join(rootDir, 'node_modules')
  ],
  alias: {
    '@shared': 'src/app/modules/shared'
  }
},
```

**component.ts:**

```
import { FooService } from '@shared/services/foo.service'
import { BarService } from '@shared/services/bar.service'
import { BazService } from '@shared/services/baz.service'
```

To make it even more cleaner, I added an `index.d.ts` inside *services* folder and exported all my services from there, like this:

**index.d.ts:**

```
export * from './foo.service';
export * from './bar.service';
export * from './baz.service';
```

and now inside any **component:**

```
import { FooService, BarService, BazService } from '@shared/services';
```

Comment: What if your project is a library ? How do you expose these mappings to the client application ?

Comment: @Stephane have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186867/how-to-use-secondary-endpoints-to-create-api-for-angular-library) question.

Answer (score 17):

Above all answer correct, but after struggling by searching over internet n trying to understand what exactly problem and trying different troubleshooting option, I came to know **baseUrl** and **Path** how works toghether

If you use **baseUrl:"."** like below it works in VScode but not while compiling

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@myproject/*": ["src/app/*"]
    }    
}
```

As per my understanding and my working app and checked in *angular aio* code,  I suggest use as **baseUrl:"src"** like below

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@myproject/*": ["app/*"],
      "testing/*": ["testing/*"]
    }    
}
```

By having base url as source(src directory), compiler properly resolves modules.

I hope this helps to people resolve this kind of issue.

Comment: thanks that solved it. Without baseUrl as "src" compiler was trying to resolve with respect to root.

Comment: I am using Angular CLI - so I don't want to edit the webpack files... this helped me a lot.

Comment: baseUrl set to src worked for me :) Otherwise the other answers were good.

Comment: Did you try with `./` instead of `.` ?

Answer (score 8):

Not sure why but when I tried the other answers in VS2017, I was able to compile Angular without errors but I was still seeing errors in VS "Cannot find Module ...". When I set the baseUrl to `"src"` from `"."` everyone was happy.

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "src",                 // Main source directory same level as tsconfig
    "paths": {
      "app/*": [ "app/*" ],           // src/app
      "ui/*": [ "ui/*" ],             // src/ui       
      "services/*": [ "services/*" ], // src/services
      "assests/*": [ "assests/*" ],     // src/assests
      "models/*": [ "models/*" ]      // src/models
    },
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Then to import:

```
import { AppMenuComponent } from 'ui/app-menu/app-menu.component';
```

**Note:** If Visual Studio is still throwing errors try either closing and reopening the file or restarting Visual Studio to get it to recognize the new paths.

Comment: If you set ```"baseUrl": "src",``` there is no need to add ```"paths"``` anymore.

Answer (score 4):

In Angular 8, no need for the *. The * will cause error of `Cannot find module`
add this to you tsconfig.json file

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
      "@test": [ "src/app/test/" ],
      "@somthing": [ "src/app/something/" ],
      "@name": [ "src/app/name/" ]
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

## Keeping it simple

Let's keep this simple with just a few things you need to know to be able to apply this solution to any future project.

Preface: Angular doesn't set up the "usual" `@/` or `~/` `path mappings`, probably because it chose to be less opinionated on this matter.

It does however set a `baseUrl` for all imports: `./` (which means the folder that `tsconfig.json` is located in).

Which then means that any non-relative imports (those that don't start with `./` or `../`) are automatically prefixed by the `baseUrl`.

So as long as you use paths that start at this base URL for your imports, you should already have a solution! You shouldn't have problems with refactoring as long as your refactoring tool recognizes the base URL and is able to correctly apply import path refactoring.

So by default, with an unmodified TS config, your can use this kind of import and not worry about relative paths becoming a headache to manage:

```
// sample import taking into consideration that there is
// a baseUrl set up for all imports which get prefixed to
// all imports automatically:

import { ComingSoonComponentModule } from 'src/app/components/coming-soon/coming-soon.module';
```

## Another solution

But if you really want to use something like a `@/` prefix, you can just as easily do that with a simple `path mapping`, like this:

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  // ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    // notice that the mapping below is relative to the baseUrl: `src/app/*` is in fact `{baseUrl}src/app/*`, ie. `./src/app/*`.
    "paths": { "@/*": ["src/app/*"] },
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

Then you can import as either one of these:

```
import { ComingSoonComponentModule } from 'src/app/components/coming-soon/coming-soon.module';
import { ComingSoonComponentModule } from '@/components/coming-soon/coming-soon.module';
```

#### Things to remember:

1. `paths` tsconfig option is relative to `baseUrl` option (so keep in mind and use relative paths for the `paths` keys).
2. `*` - the star is the specified module path (as per your specification in code, where you import), everything else is a prefix or suffix to be added, as per your specification in tsconfig, to the final path.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Stackblitz and none of the above solutions worked, even including from `src/app/...` like Paul mentioned. And I believe this is due to the fact that paths specified in ***tsconfig.json*** are not supported on [**Stack blitz**](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/220)

The only solution I found was to use `../` which effectively goes one folder back from the file. They can be used multiple times to go multiple folders back.

For example, let's say the component I'm working on is in `src/app/components/mycomponent`. However, the file I want to include is located in `src/app/shared/myservice`. Simply including `src/app/shared/myservice/service` did not work on Stackblitz. So I would have had to use `../../shared/myservice/service` instead. The first `../` directs to `src/app/components` and the second resolves the directory to `src/app` where from there you could access the shared folder.

Answer (score -2):

Ive got a MUCH simpler solution to this problem. In your "tsconfig.json" simply set the baseURL to an empty string:

```
"baseUrl": ""
```

Now you can reference paths from one file to another from your root like so:

```
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/services/product.service';
```

These are absolute paths but the way angular uses them they appear to be relative. But they work! I'm not a fan of the "path" shortcuts mentioned above as I like to know where everything is physically located and that's how and why absolute paths were invented.

Keep in mind this fixes the path issues when referencing modules and components on import or when building your Angular project, but that doesn't fix the path problems related to templates, style paths, or assets like images which use a completely different path system in Angular when you build and compile your project.

If this helps explain this goofy path system, the "angular.json" workspace file in the project root controls what the "sourceRoot" folder is, which is set by default to "src". So that is the start of your "source root" folder used by the Angular build piece. Keep in mind the Angular "workspace root" is the project folder above "src" and is the true root of the project and the compiler. So when you write "src/app/..." the root is really above "src". The angular.json apparently derives its starting folder from its current location so "src/app/" is really a relative local folder based on angular.json's  location. That is why "/src/app" will not work for the baseURL as its relative to angular.json, I believe.

By default this "src" folder for Angular is what all the build paths resolve to when you build/compile your project. I suspect webpack looks at that same "sourceRoot" "src" value as well in angular.json when it resolves.

After a lot of struggle I found by setting the baseURL in tsconfig to "" rather than "." or "./" you can now use these full paths as long as you start with the "src" folder. These types of absolute paths to me make more sense as now you know visually where everything is from the top root down, rather than going up and down trees of files. That's just crazy!

I have no idea why the Angular kids use those goofy relative path systems. These "./" paths are completely useless and make navigating MUCH harder, in both the compiler path resolution system AND the HTML/URL path resolution systems they use. I think if they had taken the time to learn why and when developers used relative paths they might have realized its not very useful in a wide range of environments to assume every file references every other file from its local folder.