# Replace Long Path for a Shortened Path in angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using the Angular CLI. How do I convert a path from:

```
import {AppConfig, AppConfigInterface} from '../../../app.config';
```

to something like:

```
import {AppConfig, AppConfigInterface} from 'root/app.config';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoiding relative paths in Angular CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460810/avoiding-relative-paths-in-angular-cli)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

try this in tsconfig.json:

```js
  {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@services/*": ["app/services/*"] // here!
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have this working on angular 7? 
"Option 'paths' cannot be used without specifying '--baseUrl' option."
even after specifying a baseUrl option, the path alias doesn't work. "cannot find module '@services/'. This worked fine in angular 6.

Comment: @seabass did you find any solution with angular 7?

Comment: yes, i'm on angular 8 now but had this working with 7 as well. 
tsconfig.json
"baseUrl":"projects/myproject/src"
"paths": { "@services": ["app/modules/services/"] }

Answer (score 7):

I want to draw the attention that editing only the `tsconfig.json` will be effective in the code completion and building via the ts compiler. the Agular-CLI, however, can't recognize the defined address to the true paths as long as you do not define them, in addition, in the `tsconfig.app.json`. ng serve will show build `error TS2307: Cannot find module '@...`

Whereas, restricting definition into the latter will make the ts 
IntelliSense compiler show them as unrecognized paths

In short: define the paths in both `tsconfig` and `tsconfig.app` JSON files

Comment: This is very helpful.  It can be improved by the addition of saying _how_ to define the paths in each.  Then this would be shoe-in for very top answer.  As it stands, it must be combined with the others in order to be useful.

Answer (score 5):

I found this question when tried to resolve `scss`. I found current approach will not work because of this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8117)

workaround is to add `stylePreprocessorOptions` to `.angular-cli.json` so it will resolve all styles within the directory

```
{
    "apps": [{
        ...
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
            "includePaths": [
                "./app/global-styles"
            ]
        },
        ...
    }]
}
```

for server-side rendering you will need to add this for both `ssr` and main app build -  otherwise you will get `NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\...\ClientApp\dist-server\main.bundle.js'`

```
{
    "apps": [{
            ...
            "outDir": "dist",
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                "includePaths": [
                    "./app/global-styles"
                ]
            },
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
            "name": "ssr",
            "outDir": "dist-server",
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                "includePaths": [
                    "./app/global-styles"
                ]
            },
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How do you reference these global styles from a `.scss` file?

Comment: as far as I remember it should work as `@import utils.scss` and it will be imported from `global-styles` directory

Answer (score 0):

angular cli default modules directory is defined in  /angular-cli.json
you can try '/app.config' if you need the root