# Angular 2: External Stylesheet Import

Tags: css, angular

I am simply trying to import a stylesheet to my component and I keep getting an error that it cannot be found:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'repositioning',
    templateUrl: './repositoning.html',
    styleUrls: ["app/vertical-timeline.css"]
})
```

...and the file is there:

```
MacBook-Pro:app user$ ls
app.component.ts    app.module.ts       main.ts
app.html        app.scss        vertical-timeline.css
```

am I missing something simple?

Comment: Did you try with ./vertical-timeline.css?

Comment: Either use a relative path or see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41460972/3001761 for how to do absolute paths (if you're using the CLI, otherwise YMMV).

Comment: I've tried all logical paths.  I thought maybe there was something else

Comment: are you using angular-cli? Either way, does your app look for `css` or `scss` files?

Comment: I'm fooling around with Ionic and I'm not sure how to check that..