# short way to import components and modules

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I used @angular/cli to create my app. when my app size increases it becomes quite difficult to mention the paths of imports for components/modules/scss used

for example, if a component structure went deep enough. to import we have to mention `import {something} from '../../../../someComponent'` goes on.

Is there a way we can define them somewhere like a schema can be defined

for example:

Schema.json

```
{
"someComponent":"../../../../someComponent',
 "otherComponent:"../../"
}
```

and we can directly import as `import {someComponent} from 'someComponent;` and can be imported easily anywhere

Is there any method like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoiding relative paths in Angular CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460810/avoiding-relative-paths-in-angular-cli)

Comment: thanks..is there any way for scss to be done like that.

Comment: I've never tried, the style file is created in the same place as the component class so it's just `'./whatever.component.scss'`.

Comment: yeah, I tried that too but not working. I am trying to avoid redefining variables. now I created a shared scss and importing it wherever required. but it is also making me mad when application goes deeper

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749973/es6-import-using-at-sign-in-path-in-a-vue-js-project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paths` can be added in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,  
    "paths": {
      ...,
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Then import absolutely from `app/` or `components/` instead of relative to the current file:

```
import {TextInputConfiguration} from "@components/configurations";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use barrel in your app.

For example you component:

```
// heroes/folder/deep/another/deep/folder/hero.component.ts
export class HeroComponent {}
```

Now you can define barrel in any folder of your project, which exports this module (it is called **index** by convention)

```
export * from './heroes/folder/deep/another/deep/folder/hero.component.ts'; // relative path to current folder
```

You can define as many barrels as you want.

You can read more in [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html#!#B)