# How to use secondary endpoints to create API for Angular library

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular5, ng-packagr

**Scenario:**

I created a custom UI library using `ng-packagr`, exported custom `components` and some model classes.

**Problem:**

In main project, `import` statement works fine for exported components but it doesn't work for exported classes and `webpack` fails to compile giving error:

> module not found error can't resolve `my-custom-library/models`

**Library project code:**

Model class: *src/app/modules/my-custom-module/models/my-model.ts*

```
export class MyModel {
  constructor() {
    // default values for props here
  }

  // ...props here
}
```

Index file: *src/app/modules/my-custom-module/models/index.ts*

```
export * from './my-model';
export * from './my-other-model';
```

Export file at root: *models.ts*

```
export * from './src/app/modules/my-custom-module/models/index';
```

`ng-packagr` file at root: *public_api.ts*

```
export * from './models';

export * from './src/app/modules/my-custom-module/my-custom-module.module';
export * from './src/app/modules/my-custom-module/components/index';
```

**Main project code:**

```
import {MyCustomModule} from 'my-custom-library'; // works
import {MyModel} from 'my-custom-library'; // works
import {MyModel} from 'my-custom-library/models'; // does not works
```

**Purpose:**
Simplifying and dividing the UI library API for end developers.

I believe, I'm missing something about mapping `webpack` module resolution because VS Code recognizes the `import`, intellisense works and even `Ctrl + Click` navigates to right file but `webpack` fails in compilation.

[Git Issue](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/issues/992)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve my required API pattern using [`Seconday End Points`](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/secondary-entrypoints.md).

Credits: [**Alan Agius**](https://github.com/alan-agius4) at [Git Issue](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/issues/992)

Comment: Looking at this (and having a go at implementing it), if I want 5 secondary endpoints, it means maintaining 5 copies of my code, and my ng build runs over and builds all 5 copies... or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @blomster: I believe there's something you're missing, though I can't be sure without looking at actual code/requirement.