# angular: custom imports - specifying path to file

Tags: angular, import

Is there another way - a better cleaner way to specify the path to my imports? I am referring to the dots and forward slashes

I have something like this:

```
import { Product } from '../../../../../../@core/model/v2/domain/product';
import { ConfigService } from '../../../../../../@core/data/config.service';
import { ProductMappingContainer } from '../../../../../../@core/model/v2/dto/productMappingContainer';
import { AddProductModalSource } from '../../../../../../@core/model/v2/types/addProductModalSource';
```

Comment: A good practice is to avoid making folder structure too much deep/nested on your project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoiding relative paths in Angular CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460810/avoiding-relative-paths-in-angular-cli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typescript compiler allows path mapping.

In your tsconfig.json file you can add baseurl:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "@shared/*":["app/modules/shared/*"],
            "@core/*":["app/modules/core/*"]
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

and then in your imports:

```
import { MyComponent } from '@shared/components/mycomponent'
```

This is taken from this [medium-itnext article](https://itnext.io/angular-tips-and-tricks-ec7f548670c1)