# How to set angular class reference path fro deployment?

Tags: angular

I am referencing a file in my component using different paths.

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
```

or

```
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';
```

Both of them are working, but first way is more easy to use.

But may be any issue in production for first path? `for example src/file not found.`

Comment: No, because it is resolved when creating the (production) build. It may be different for assets (such as images) referenced in templates or styles though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`ABSOLUTE` VS. `RELATIVE` PATHS/LINKS**

When importing `modules` in `typescript` they are usually separated in two:

> - Importing libraries modules, which is quite nice, since we use only the name and they are resolved from *node_modules* folder
> - Importing modules from our own application

When importing modules from our own application there are two way of addressing

- `Relative Paths` e.g: import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';
- `Absolute Paths` e.g: import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

There are full of examples that use `relative paths`  but it goes quickly wrong when the file we need is several levels up or down. Then we get something like:

```js
import { foo } from ‘../../../../bar’;
```

Since `TypeScript 2.0`, we have an awesome compiler setting called `baseUrl`, and we can configure it in the `tsconfig.json` file like:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

By this way you can use absolute path like this:

```
import { foo } from ‘app/bar’
```

For more information about `absolute` paths check this quick guide: **[Use absolute paths for module imports](https://adrianfaciu.dev/posts/module-imports/)**

In addition, there is similar discussion here:

[Avoiding relative paths in Angular CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41460810/4185370)

& check both thees answers of this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41460972/4185370

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319965/4185370

So, as a conclusion the first one `absolute` paths are better, but with the **right configuration** through `tsconfig.json`.